# Azure Devops - Restrict pipeline run permission to all users except for a specific group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, user-permissions

I want to allow only specific group of users to run specific pipelines in Azure Devops.

I created a group for the allowed user and set their "Queue Builds" permissions to Allow.
Also, I changed the Contributors "Queue Builds" permissions to Deny.

Unfortunately, since the users in the new group are also members of Contributors group, they inherited the Deny permission, which overrides the "Allowed" (This is the expected behavior according to ADO documentation)

My question is - Is there any way to restrict permissions for all users except for specific group, or the only solution is to create a new group for restricted users, and add all the other project members there?